# IllegalStateException on DataBindingUtil.setContentView: Restoring the Navigation back stack failed, current destination null

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-jetpack-navigation

For some users, my app seems to crash regularly at or near app start. It's been an issue I've been trying to figure out for a while but I haven't had much success since I haven't been able to reproduce it on any of our test devices and this is also my first time working with the AndroidX Navigation components.

It happens on this line:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

And this is the relevant stack trace from crashlytics, the issue looks like this:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
Restoring the Navigation back stack failed: destination com.company.app:id/home_navigation cannot be found from the current destination null


Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.app/com.company.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54 in com.company.app:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #54 in com.company.app/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
```

In my activity_main.xml, this is the fragment that it is failing to inflate and line 54 is the last line:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_navigation" />
```

So @navigation/home_navigation, the navigation graph, cannot be found in the current destination, which means what exactly? How do I stop it from attempting to navigate? How do I make sure it doesn't crash? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means, that it fails to parse XML of `navigation/home_navigation.xml`.
You may replace the `fragment` with a `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`.

And it should also generate a named binding ...

```
ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
```

Comment: But why would it fail to parse navigation/home_navigation.xml only some of the time? What would cause it to only sometimes fail?

I've tried swapping the fragment for FragmentContainerView but ultimately went back when it didn't solve my problem and I found an example project that used Fragment for this.

Comment: @BooleanCheese You're referring to an obsolete example ...and when this example also suggested to use `DataBindingUtil`, then it's probably not a good example at all. That question is also lacking relevant details, such as the `navigation/home_navigation.xml` - which may not completely invalid, but may feature invalid nodes / values.

Comment: `Binary XML file line #54 in com.company.app/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment` ...is all one needs to know. This error message is quite explicit and not bogus at all.

Comment: you are correct about using FragmentContainerView but I believe you should add the following for me it as the accepted answer: The NavHostFragment must be referenced via findViewById. Viewbinding does not work for this because android studio flags it as a compiler error and prevents casting the FragmentContainerView as NavHostFragment. This prevented me from implementing FragmentContainerView correctly because I was working on the assumption that viewbinding works the same as FindViewByID.

Comment: This is the bug report that lead me to the correct syntax https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973?pli=1

Comment: *Add the issue tracker link and maybe add a bit about viewbinding and findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment) not working and needing to use findviewbyid(R.id.nav_host_fragment as explained in the issue tracker to be able to cast it to NavHostFragment, then I'll mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: So the issue wasn't related to databinding but I use both databinding and viewbinding in my app. Is there a reason you suggest not to use databinding?

Comment: I'd suggest to use data-binding instead of view-binding; where view-binding is the lite version with less functionality and a few kilobytes difference in size. But I'd disagree to some degree, because the correct methods to use would be `findFragmentById()` and then `findNavController()`. For example: https://github.com/syslogic/androidx-github/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/io/syslogic/github/activity/NavHostActivity.java